# How to differentiate email service provider domains from company domains?

Tags: email, dns

I am building an application that receives emails and needs to to differentiate email service provider domains (e.g.: @gmail, @hotmail, @outlook, @yahoo etc) from company domains (@contoso.com).

I would like to do this by maintaining a list of known email service provider domains and checking if the domain is present in this list. If it isn't, then assume it is a company domain. Is there a list of known email service providers?

Other options such as an API can be considered.

How would you approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have found [a list of known free email service provider domains on Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/ammarshah/f5c2624d767f91a7cbdc4e54db8dd0bf).

However, this doesn't quite cover the question as paid email service providers that are not company domains are not on this list.